# Omniauth custom provider and strategy w/ doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth, csrf, doorkeeper

I have a custom OAuth2 provider (is a Rails app) built with [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper)

and have a custom client strategy built with OmniAuth

The problem is when I set this in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :mystrategy, "apikey", "secret"
```

Then i will got this error:

```
(mystrategy) Callback phase initiated.
(mystrategy) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: 
OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError
```

And if i change the config in `devise.rb` to be

```
config.omniauth :mystrategy, "apikey", "secret", {:provider_ignores_state => true}
```

Then everything is all right ...

I can't figure out what cause this problem. it seems the problem is the Rails' CSRF protection?

Comment: IIRC I have set it as  config.omniauth :strategy_name, SiteConfig.client_id, SiteConfig.client_secret, :scope => 'public' . The scope is set as public

Comment: I thought the scope is not the cause of this problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but setting as "public" works in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing omniauth-oauth2 to version

```
gem "omniauth-oauth2", "~> 1.0.2"
```